# Remote desktop connection closed when use VPN

Tags: vpn, remote

I have an ubuntu machine on a server and I connect to it using remote desktop connection. When I use a VPN on it and connect to a VPN the remote connection disconnected. How can I handle the traffic and set the remote connection traffic not use the VPN tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

The remote desktop is probably using an ip adress for the connection.
If you change your ip adress it will lose connection.

So you could try to first connect with the vpn service and after that try to connect to your server.